How to start player 2 in the Aliens Konami game from browser?
I am playing the Konami's Aliens in the browser.
I would like to start player2 (the coop mode), despite that I've set the start player 2 button it just doesn't work. Pushing the game controller icon then adjusting the buttons for P2 (assuming P2 stands for Player2).
Any idea/experience would be welcome.
